# How can I extract data from a MySQL database in random order?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a tabel named "intrebari" with fields "id" and "intrebare". How can I extract that in a table, but in random order?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, i'll write an answer

Comment: and that's all? it will extract in random order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to extract all records, and want to sort the randomly retrieved records, use,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10) Tb ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Tb is just a table alias. Like we use in, select a.id, a.name from  long_table_name a;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the entire contents of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `intrebari` ORDER BY RAND()
```

If however you only want a small subset of a large table, it may be more efficient to generate 5 random numbers in the range with php and use `WHERE  IN` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use rand() function

SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
use [rand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

```
SELECT * FROM `intrebari`
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about getting random result from the table randomly then you can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this was useful, please mark it as Useful..Thanks